# Overwriting last terminal output(multiple lines)

Tags: bash, shell, process, refresh, overwrite

I want to write a script that refreshes every s seconds(s given as parameter),and it displays the users sorted by the number of running processes.

my code so far is:

```
#!/bin/bash

s=$1
tput sc;
while true
do
    ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr
    sleep $s
    tput rc;
    tput el

done
```

I want to get something like a refresh effect but all this code does is to concatenate at the last output.Is there a way i can make it overwrite last lines.(P.S. further i must implement to show only top n users(n is given from keyboard) so i kinda need to link it to this one.

Comment: Is this not working? Does using `ed` (clear to end of screen) instead of `el` (clear to end of line) fix things?

Comment: That would be more visually disruptive.

Comment: @EtanReisner changing el with ed fixed the problem.Thank you

Comment: @EtanReisner Later edit:It worked the first time i used it. Now. with the same code , it concatenates again.

Comment: Define "concatenates" here more specifically please. I'm not sure I understand the problem.

Comment: @EtanReisner As i told above , the script shows top n users .(i fixed the top n users thing).If i give to n the value 2 for example it will print on terminal two lines , each containing an user and the number of processes.After the sleep seconds pass , instead of re-write the two lines from the begining , it writes them on the imediate line after the first two lines.I hope i explained good.i don't know what is the problem because the first time i runed i it worked just fine, and then it stopped workin(i even tried it on 2 files but it runs the same)

Comment: @EtanReisner I sent the script to somebody else and it runs for her.Then restarted the temrinal and now it works for me too .Thanks for help and for your time

Comment: @EtanReisner I figured out what the problem was. If the terminal didn't have the needed space until the end of screen then it "concatenates" them, but if i run a clear command then it works just fine.Thanks again

Comment: If it doesn't have enough space then when it prints it will have to scroll to fit them all and then the `rc` will only reset into the middle of the output lines. I think that is what you are talking about.

Answer (score 1):

You could try adding the erase-line capability to the end of each line, e.g.,

```
#!/bin/bash

s=$1
tput sc;
EL=$(tput el)
while true
do
    tput rc
    ps hax -o user | sort | uniq -c | sort -nr | sed -e "s/\$/$EL/"
    sleep $s

done
```

Comment: That isn't informative (it worked in xterm, here).  Perhaps there is something amiss with your `TERM` variable versus the terminal.